# Indicate programming language in a file without extension

Tags: programming-languages, text-editor, syntax-highlighting, file-extension, file-type

When writing executable scripts, and declarative configuration files that use a common language (eg. Python), I often find it undesirable to add an extension to the file name. Many syntax-highlighting text editor (eg. Geany) are subsequently unable to automatically determine the filetype.

Is there any standard method for indicating to editors the type of source in the file?

Comment: Why do you find it undesirable to add an extension to the file name? Just curious...

Comment: @Tarydon:

Im the same way none of my shell scripts have extensions its extra typing for no reason - in most terms they are treated as a executable so its jsut extra typing on the CLI.

Comment: I thought that's what tab-complete was for. :)

Comment: on unix, executability is transparent and doesn't require that a file is a binary. as an example, what if i wanted to replace an existing binary executable with a shell script that wraps it.

Comment: @fennec - Windoze does not have a competent tab-complete.

Comment: @amphetamachine: Windoze is not competent.

Comment: @amphetamachine Windows with cygwin has rather competent tab-completion (bash) and very competent tab-completion (zsh). But yeah, this is like cheating :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Typically the shebang line is used as a fall-back.

For example, a Ruby script without an extension would begin with:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
```

Comment: Of note is that this is typically how file(1) and vim's filetype.vim determine script language.

Comment: I chose this answer because it's the most obvious fallback, and the easiest to implement.

Answer (score 21):

### Vim

Vim has a concept called a [modeline](http://VimDoc.SourceForge.Net/htmldoc/usr_21.html#21.6). A modeline is a specially formatted line either withinin the first or last 5 lines of the textfile, which allows you to `:setlocal` local variables. For example, for C:

```
 /* vi: set filetype=c fileencoding=UTF-8 shiftwidth=4 tabstop=4 expandtab */
```

or Ruby:

```
 # vi: set filetype=ruby fileencoding=UTF-8 shiftwidth=2 tabstop=2 expandtab
```

[Some more documentation](http://VimDoc.SourceForge.Net/htmldoc/options.html#modeline).

### Emacs

Emacs has a similar concept, called [File Variables](http://GNU.Org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Specifying-File-Variables.html#Specifying-File-Variables).

File Variables are either specified at the beginning of the file (in the first line, or if there is a shebang line, then in the second) in this form:

```
/* *-* mode: cc c-basic-offset: 4; tab-width: 4; indent-tabs-mode: nil *-* */
```

or at the end:

```
# Local Variables:
# mode: ruby
# coding: utf-8
# c-basic-offset: 2
# tab-width: 2
# indent-tabs-mode: nil
# End:
```

### jEdit

jEdit calls this [buffer-local properties](http://jEdit.Org/users-guide/buffer-local.html). The have to sit within the first or last 10 lines and look like this:

```
# :mode=ruby:indentSize=2:tabSize=2:noTabs=true:
```

jEdit also uses the shebang line as a fallback for mode detection.

### Komodo Edit

There is a plugin called [Komode](http://Community.ActiveState.Com/forum/komode-modeline-support-komodo/) (pun intended) which adds modeline support to Komodo Edit:

```
# komode: le=unix language=ruby codepage=utf8 tab=2 notabs indent=2
```

It also understands a limited subset of Vim modelines.

### Others

A lot of other editors also have either their own variants of this, or support one of the above (usually Vim).

### Python / Ruby encoding

Both Ruby 1.9 and Python require that the encoding for non-ASCII source files be explicitly specified. Fortunately, they do this in a way that is compatible with both Emacs and Vim modelines. (Basically, they look for the string `coding` followed by a non-word character followed by whitespace followed by a valid encoding name. Both Vim's `fileencoding=` and Emacs' `coding:` satisfy these requirements.)

### Modeline Generator

Here is a simple [modeline generator](http://Wireshark.Org/tools/modelines.html), which generates modelines for Vim, Emacs and jEdit.

Answer (score 0):

This works for many editors if you're using non-standard shebangs:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# filetype=python
```

Comment: Actually it doesn't work. The editors I thought did this were actually doing fancy regex's on the first argument to env.