# How to detect .o / .a / compiled object /executable c/c++ without extension? (to then issue 'what' on file to see what it was compiled with)

Tags: executable, detection, file-type, .obj, .a

How can I detect if a file is a compiled object ( .o .a (library)) or executable, without the file extension?

I want to do this so that I can then issue the standard what command to see what .c / .h files were used to build the binary.

Presumably there would be some kind of header at the beginning of the file or some other pattern to look for (?)

Had a look around here and elsewhere a little already but the answers tend to be about MIME types and web development / handling of such files:

- [Indicate programming language in a file without extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1984072/indicate-programming-language-in-a-file-without-extension)
- http://forums.devshed.com/c-programming-42/how-can-detect-filetype-for-files-without-extension-695199.html
- http://cboard.cprogramming.com/c-programming/125865-how-can-detect-filetype-files-without-extension.html

Comment: (If you're in Unix/Linux, does the `file` command do anything helpful?)

Comment: +1 Yep it does! e.g.: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), for GNU/Linux 2.2.5, dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.2.5, not stripped       -- I can use regex to parse this text data so this should work for me. So why didn't you submit this as your answer rather than a comment? Don't be shy! If you submit this as an answer I would be likely +1 it and accept it, I'll give others a chance but your suggestion looks pretty good to me.

Comment: Because it was a bit of a guess :P I'll submit then :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If  you're in Unix/Linux, the `file` command is useful for determining file type of files without relying on a file extension.

It looks at things like "is this a special device rather than a normal file", then looks for "magic numbers" which identify certain file format, etc.

Comment: +1 That should do what I need - thanks: e.g. ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), for GNU/Linux 2.2.5, dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.2.5, not stripped -- I can use regex to parse this text data so this should work for me.